# Has many relationship help in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models questions and answers. and a question has_many answers.
How can I find out all the questions which don't have any answer?

Comment: @corroded That only works for a single question.

Comment: Oh yeah, i was thinking of a for loop of all questions in my head. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest adding `:counter_cache` to `Answer` model. Then you can do something like this in `Question` model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  named_scope :unanswered, :conditions => {:answers_count => 0}
end
```

The `Answer` model would look like this

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Comment: Really like this method over creating SQL which requires future adaptation if the schema changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers

  def self.unanswered
    find_by_sql("select * from questions where id not in (select DISTINCT question_id from answers) ORDER BY updated_at DESC")
  end
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

In controller

```
@unanswered= Question.unanswered
```

FOR PAGINATION

```
  def self.unanswered
    find_by_sql("select * from questions where id not in (select DISTINCT question_id from answers) ORDER BY updated_at DESC")
  end


@unanswered= Question.unanswered
@unanswered.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

As this fetch all the recors and then use pagination Try Following

```
  def self.unanswered(page_no=1, per_page=10)
    find_by_sql("select * from questions where id not in (select DISTINCT question_id from answers) ORDER BY updated_at DESC").paginate(:page => page_no, :per_page => per_page)
  end


@unanswered= Question.unanswered(params[:page], params[:per_page])
```

Comment: isnt there any other way of doing this using active record. Means not by using find_by_sql? cause i am using will_paginate plugin. For all questions i m using
 Question.paginate :page => page_number,  :order => 'updated_at DESC'

Comment: for your edit section (ie pagination part). You are trying to fetch all the records in the first query. in that case when number of records will be high something like 15000. This query will take a long time. dont u think so?

Comment: i think you are right i edited my question for the same problem please check if it works for you. m not sute though :). Cheer's

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to adopt a straight SQL approach as described by Salil rather than a more ActiveRecord approach as suggested by Eimantas then you may want to use the following SQL

```
SELECT * FROM questions as q 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM answers AS a WHERE a.question_id = q.id)
```

As opposed to

```
select * from questions 
where id not in (select DISTINCT question_id from answers)
```

The former query performed 8 times faster for me on a table of 140000 rows with 10% of the rows having no answer. I expect this would vary from engine to engine dependant upon the % of unanswered questions.

Eimantas solution is nice if you create a column called answers_count on your questions table then ActiveRecord will maintain that for you and that should be very fast.